# Given 7 points on the plane , what is the maximum number of times we can have the same distance

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, problem-solving

Assuming the points to be $a_{1},a_{2}\cdots,a_{7}$ we can put them into the vertices and the centre of a regular hexagon, where we can find $12$ distances which are equal and the remaining $9$ distances are non equal. But how can I show that this is the maximum number and it cannot exceed $12$?

Comment: Just the ordinary Euclidean distance.

Comment: HINT: To see that 12 of the $a_i$ can be equal, think about very uncomplicated polygons that have lots of equal-length edges. Equivalently, imagine you had 12 equal-length matchsticks; how could you arrange them to get lots of their ends to coincide? Play around a bit. Then all you have to do is show that more than 12 is impossible.

Comment: Can't you arrange them and calculate the distances explicitly?

Comment: @DS I am sorry I did not get how you are approaching the problem.

Comment: This is a bit laborious, but you can do something along: Show that a unit distance graph of 7 vertices and more than 13 edges have a set of 4 triangles, with no three triangles sharing an edge. The triangles forms a rigid structure in the plane, so induce a unique unit distance embedding. From this, you can do a case by case analysis. Note that extension of this problem to more vertices is still open (erdos unit distance problem)